# Height of circle bulge along given arc

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, circles, arc-length

I am trying to determine line of sight along the surface of the earth between 2 points.  Earth's curvature is a consideration. 2 points on the earth $A$ and $B$ are distance $s$ apart.  At intervals along  $\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$, I need to determine the height of the bulge of the earth.  This diagram helps visualize the problem:

[image]

The article [How much does the earth curve](https://www.themathdoctors.org/how-much-does-the-earth-curve/) gives a great explanation of how to find the bulge of a circle, given the radius, and the length of a chord.  This was a promising lead, but ultimately not quite what I need.  This gives $y$ as a function of $x$, stricly in the cartesian plane.

In my scenario, I need a function for, we'll call it, $y_r$, the component of the radius between the chord and the arc defined by $\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$.  This refers to the length of the line between the 2 blue dots in the following drawing:

[image]

This needs to be a function of $d$, the length of the arc as it expands from $A$ to $B$, whose domain would be the scalar value between 0 and the length $\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$.  I would expect the range would begin at $d = 0$, swell to the value of $y$ at $d = \overset{\huge\frown}{AB} / 2$, and then shrink back to 0 at $d = \overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$.

How can I write such a function $f$ for $y_r = f(d)$?

Comment: Clarification: For the input $d$ of your function, are you measuring along the chord $\overline{AB}$ or along the arc $\stackrel{\;\;\mbox{$\large{\frown}$}}{AB}$? You've written conflicting things to suggest both, but these are not the same.

Comment: @SammyBlack sorry I didn't know I could do the $\overset{\huge\frown}{overset}$, I edited the question

Comment: And the length of the chord is fixed (equivalently, points $A$ and $B$ are given)? This fixed distance (length of the *chord*) is described as $d$ at the beginning of your post, which contradicts your use of $d$ later as a measure of arc length. Perhaps we can call this later arc length $s$ (a standard symbol for such lengths)?

Comment: @SammyBlack correct, I edited my question to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really very simple.  Define

$\theta_{AB} =  \dfrac{\overset{\frown}{AB}}{R}$

And define

$ \theta = \dfrac{d}{R} $

Then

$ y_r = R - H \sec( \dfrac{\theta_{AB}}{2} - \theta ) $

Where $ H = R \cos( \dfrac{\theta_{AB}}{2} ) $

Put together

$ y_r = R \left( 1 - \dfrac{ \cos \left( \dfrac{\theta_{AB}}{2} \right) }{ \cos \left( \dfrac{\theta_{AB}}{2} - \theta \right) } \right) $

Comment: Would you mind explaining this term a bit?  $ y_r = R - H \sec( \dfrac{\theta_{AB}}{2} - \theta ) $ - Where does that come from?  I see how you're getting $H$, but I'm having a hard time understanding this secant term

Comment: Let $E$ be the intersection of the ray (blue line segment) from the center and $AE$. Consider the right triangle $\triangle CED$, the angle $C =  \frac{1}{2} \theta_{AB} - \theta$, the adjacent is $H$, so the hypotenuse $= H \sec(C) = H \sec(\frac{1}{2} \theta_{AB} - \theta)$